# Form scroll down after selection of value into dropdown

Tags: codenameone

I see issue when a date value selected in the drop-down will automatically push the content in the form downwards and never gets refreshed.

I have used  content.setScrollableY(true) which make the form scrollable. But here the problem is happening when I select the date value in the drop-down, where i have to scroll the dates to select which will internally scrolling the content in the form.Please advise

Code:

```
Form hi = new Form("Pick", BoxLayout.y());        
Label emptyLbl1 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl1.setUIID("Seperator");

Label emptyLbl2 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl2.setUIID("Seperator");

Label emptyLbl3 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl3.setUIID("Seperator");

Label emptyLbl4 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl4.setUIID("Seperator");

Label emptyLbl5 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl5.setUIID("Seperator");

Label emptyLbl6 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl6.setUIID("Seperator");

Label emptyLbl7 = new Label(" ");
emptyLbl7.setUIID("Seperator");

Picker p = new Picker();
p.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
hi.add(p).add(emptyLbl1).add(emptyLbl7);
CheckBox pickStartTime;
CheckBox pickEndTime;
pickStartTime = new CheckBox("Edit Start Time");
pickStartTime.setOppositeSide(true);
pickStartTime.setHeight(Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(6.5f));
pickStartTime.setSelected(false);
pickStartTime.setUIID("CheckArea");
pickEndTime = new CheckBox("Edit End Time");
pickEndTime.setOppositeSide(true);
pickEndTime.setHeight(Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(6.5f));
pickEndTime.setSelected(false);
pickEndTime.setUIID("CheckArea");
Picker timePicker1 = new Picker();
Picker datePicker1 = new Picker();
Picker dateTimePicker1 = new Picker();
timePicker1.setUIID("TextField");
datePicker1.setUIID("TextField");
dateTimePicker1.setUIID("TextField");
Button navigate = new Button("Navigation");
navigate.setUIID("NavigateButton");        
CommonUtil.makeBorderRound(navigate);
Picker p1 = new Picker();
p1.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
Label clock = new Label("--:--", "Clock");
hi.add(p1).add(pickStartTime).add(emptyLbl2).add(navigate).add(clock);
Picker p2 = new Picker();
p2.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
hi.add(pickEndTime).add(p2).add(emptyLbl3).add(emptyLbl5);
Picker p3 = new Picker();
p3.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
Button finishActivity = new Button("Finish Activity");
CommonUtil.makeBorderRound(finishActivity);
finish.setTextPosition(LEFT);
CommonUtil.addSideMenu(this);
hi.add(p3).add(emptyLbl6).add(finish);
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen to me:

```
Form hi = new Form("Pick", BoxLayout.y());
Picker p = new Picker();
p.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
hi.add(p);

hi.show();
```

Make sure you are using the lightweight picker.

Comment: I have added the modified code. I cannot isolate the code to show the form move downwards but form is moving upwards with the test code. Please let me know what can be done to fix the issues like this.thanks

Comment: I don't see how that's different from my test case. Please try to isolate it to a separate project so I can reproduce the issue

Comment: this issue is happening when the form has more controls and date control is at the bottom of the form.Please advise.

Comment: Adding `for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 100 ; iter++) {
            hi.add(new Label("Filler"));
        }` before the picker doesn't change anything either.